# Whatsapp Channel: Broken invitation link + Channel cannot be found

Tags: search, hyperlink, whatsapp, channel

my employer recently created a new Whatsapp Channel, but we are facing two problems:

First, the channel cannot be found when people search for it manually (if you click on “Find channels” and then type in the name of the Channel).

Second, for some people, the invitation link does not seem to work at all, while it works for others. Considering that its not possible to search for the Channel manually, this is of course a problem.

We started today promoting our new Whatsapp Channel on other social media platforms but receive many questions about the two points mentioned above.

Can anyone help?

We already tried opening the invitation link from different devices, but I dont think thats the problem. The invitation link simply seems to work for some but not for others